# JavaFX: KeyEvent allowing only digits, letters, symbols and space

Tags: javafx, java-8, keyevent

I am trying to write an event handler that I can use the text that the user entered.

I tried using `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED` but it is also giving the unicode characters for keys like <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd> etc. All I want to capture are the characters that you can (visually) enter into a textfield, which means it should *ignore* <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, functional buttons (e.g. <kbd>F1</kbd>), modifier buttons, navigational buttons and lock buttons.

I also tried `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` but `KeyCode` only has `isDigit()` and `isLetter()`; it does not have `isSymbol()`.

How should I go about implementing this?

Comment: how does you implement that? Please post some code!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I don't think there is a KeyEvent that does this out of the box. In your case wouldn't it be better to just listen to the ValueProperty of your TextField and thus only act if the text actually changes? Something like:

```
myTextField.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue obsVal, String oldVal, String newVal) -> {doWhateverYouNeedWith_newVal;});
```

Note thought that this listener will be called even if you change the text programmatically, not just when the user types something.